# ffmpeg -sample_fmt error under Windows

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, video-conversion, audio-conversion

I was tasked to convert a simple audio track on windows using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i mySound.mp3 -acodec libmp3lame -ar 48000 -ab 128k -ac 2 -sample_fmt s16 out.mp3
```

However it fails miserably and instead I get this error from ffmpeg:

```
[libmp3lame @ 0000000002569480] Specified sample format u8 is invalid or not supported
```

If I omit the `sample_fmt` flag the convertion continues smoothly.
I am using the latest static stable zeranoe build.

Why is this happening and how may I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the complete `ffmpeg` console output as mentioned in the [tag:ffmpeg] tag description.

Comment: Also please add what you want to convert to. It's not clear what your objective is.